# Cartesian products and selects in the from clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to use a select in the from clause but I keep getting an Cartesian product.

```
select 
customer.customer_name
,orders.order_date
,order_line.num_ordered
,order_line.quoted_price
,part.descript
,amt_billed
from (select order_line.num_ordered*part.price as amt_billed
    from order_line
    join part
    on order_line.part_num = part.part_num
    ) billed
,customer
join orders
on customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
join order_line
on orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
join part
on order_line.part_num = part.part_num;
```

Don't bother looking at the rest too hard. I already know that if I remove both the subselect in the `from` clause and `amt_billed` in the select clause I don't get the Cartesian product. What am I doing wrong that's causing the Cartesian product?

Comment: You just forgot to join your subquery with one or more of the other tables. `(your subquery), customer...` it should be `(your subquery) as somename join customer [or other table] on ...`

Comment: You also have to add some column on the subquery that will allow you to join it with some table.

Comment: @JorgeCampos When I try to use `AS` in between my alias and the sub query it tells me `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. In addition, if I try using the `billed` alias in a join it tells me `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for Cartesian product is, you didn't join the sub-select with `orders` or `Part` table.

First of all you don't need that `sub-select`

```
SELECT customer.customer_name, 
       orders.order_date, 
       order_line.num_ordered, 
       order_line.quoted_price, 
       part.descript, 
       order_line.num_ordered * part.price AS amt_billed 
FROM   customer 
       JOIN orders 
         ON customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num 
       JOIN order_line 
         ON orders.order_num = order_line.order_num 
       JOIN part 
         ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: Moved those two ↑ to your first comment.