# JOIN alias does not exist and improperly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823178/cartesian-products-and-selects-in-the-from-clause) thread, the subquery in the from clause is not necessary and causes a Cartesian product, but new questions arise.

```
SELECT customer.customer_name
       ,orders.order_date
       ,order_line.num_ordered
       ,order_line.quoted_price
       ,part.descript
       ,amt_billed
FROM   (SELECT order_line.num_ordered*part.price AS amt_billed
          FROM order_line
          JOIN part
            ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num
          ) billed
           ,customer
      JOIN orders
        ON customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
      JOIN order_line
        ON orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
      JOIN part
        ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num;
```

Let us say I was determined to use the subquery in the from clause. If you read the comments, @JorgeCampos suggested I use an `AS` to establish an alias and to then write a join between the subquery and an existing table.

When I place an `AS` in between the subquery and the alias `billed`, I get a `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. Removing the `AS` and running it returns no error but a Cartesian product.

Further more, any `join` I try to make using the `billed` alias returns an `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

For reference sake, here is the ERD for the entire database: [image: Premiere_Products_ERD]

In conclusion, I want to know how this would be written if I was determined to keep the subquery in the from clause.

*I am using Oracle 11g pl/sql.*

*Update*

This:

```
SELECT customer.customer_name
       ,orders.order_date
       ,order_line.num_ordered
       ,order_line.quoted_price
       ,part.descript
       ,amt_billed
FROM (SELECT order_line.num_ordered*part.price AS amt_billed, orders.order_num
        FROM order_line
        JOIN part
          ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num
           ) AS billed
    JOIN customer
      ON customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
    JOIN billed
      ON orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
    JOIN orders
      ON customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
    JOIN order_line
      ON orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
    JOIN part
      ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num;
```

Returns this:

```
       ) AS billed
         *
ERROR at line 11:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Removing `AS` at line 11 returns this:

```
JOIN billed
     *
ERROR at line 14:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

*Update*

Thanks to @GordonLinoff, I present to you the final code!

```
SELECT customer.customer_name
       ,orders.order_date
       ,order_line.num_ordered
       ,order_line.quoted_price
       ,amt_billed
       ,part.descript
  FROM customer
    JOIN orders
      ON customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num
    JOIN order_line
      ON orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
    JOIN part
      ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT order_line.part_num
                          ,order_line.num_ordered*part.price AS amt_billed
            FROM order_line
            JOIN part
              ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num
        ) billed
      ON billed.part_num = order_line.part_num
ORDER BY customer.customer_name, orders.order_date;
```

I did as he said and removed the redundant join to customer. I also had to swap out what the subselect was joined on. If I stuck with the `num_ordered`, rows would repeat their selves whenever one part was ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle doesn't support `as` for table aliases.  So:

```
FROM (SELECT order_line.num_ordered*part.price AS amt_billed, orders.order_num
      FROM order_line JOIN
           part
           ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num
      ) billed JOIN
--------^
      Customer
      . . .
```

EDIT:

You don't need to *repeat* `billed`.  You want something like this:

```
FROM customer JOIN
     orders
     ON customer.customer_num = orders.customer_num JOIN
     order_line
     ON orders.order_num = order_line.order_num JOIN
     part
     ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num JOIN
     (SELECT order_line.order_num, order_line.num_ordered*part.price AS amt_billed
      FROM order_line JOIN
           part
           ON order_line.part_num = part.part_num
     ) billed
     ON billed.order_num = order.order_num;
```

Comment: I see. Is making a `JOIN` that references to an alias declared in the `FROM` clause also not supported by Oracle?

Comment: @ConnerSams . . . I don't understand the question in the comment.  Oracle doesn't recognize `as` for defining table aliases.  Of course, once a table alias is defined, it can be used in subsequent `on` clauses as well as `where`, `group by`, `having`, `select`, `order by` as well.

Comment: I'm talking about this: Removing AS at line 11 returns this:

    JOIN billed
            *
    ERROR at line 14:
    ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    sql oracle

Comment: @ConnerSams . . . Did you remove the comma and include the `JOIN`?

Comment: Yes, the entire query is after the second update in my post.